# Why is UFW blocking acces to SSH via Wireguard?

Tags: routing, firewall, ufw, wireguard

`192.168.100.50` is connected to `192.168.178.20` over the internet via `wg0` interface.

`wg0` is opening up the tunnel `10.102.242.1/24`.

The wireguard client interface has `10.102.242.2`.

Through a static route on `192.168.100.1` I can connect from any device in `192.168.100.0/24` to the wireguard client using `ssh admin@192.168.178.20`

**But I can only do this if I disable the `ufw` on the wireguard server.**

I tried to open port `22` on the server's `ufw` from `anywhere`, allowing it `on wg0`, `allow IN` and `OUT`. But nothing changed this.

What do I not understand about this?

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                   # allow-wireguard
22                         ALLOW       192.168.100.0/24           # SSH
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                   # SSH test
22 on wg0                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # SSH test
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # allow-wireguard
22 (v6) on wg0             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

22                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on wg0           
22 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on wg0      

Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW FWD   10.102.242.0/24 on wg0
```

`traceroute 192.168.178.20` is also showing the same behaviour. With `ufw active`:

```
traceroute to 192.168.178.20 (192.168.178.20), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1)  2.824 ms  1.136 ms  1.016 ms
 2  192.168.100.50 (192.168.100.50)  3.566 ms  1.557 ms  1.337 ms
 3  *
```

With `ufw inactive` it will instantly connect:

```
 8  * * *
 9  * 192.168.178.20 (192.168.178.20)  20.973 ms  16.469 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more testing brought my attention to the fact that I need to include the other remote subnet into the forwarding rule:

```
ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg0 to 192.168.178.0/24
```

Voilá!